# How to remove text after a 4 digit year in a file name

Tags: linux, regex, awk, text

I am looking to remove all text after the 4 digit year of movie files:

Input:
Some.Movie.Name.2011.1080p.BluRay.x265.mp4
Another.Movie.Name.1999.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4
Another.Movie.Name.II.2001.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4

Desired Output:
Some.Movie.Name.2011
Another.Movie.Name.1999
Another.Movie.Name.II.2001

I have used awk with regex:
`echo "Some.Movie.Name.2011.1080p.BluRay.x265.mp4" |awk -F'.[0-9]{4}' '{print$1}'`

Which gives me:
Some.Movie.Name

I can't find a way with awk or anything else to have it print the 4 digit year delimiter also.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
sed -E "s/(.*\.[[:digit:]]{4})\..*/\1/"
```

to achieve what you're after.

### back-check

```
for f in Some.Movie.Name.2011.1080p.BluRay.x265.mp4 Another.Movie.Name.1999.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4 Another.Movie.Name.II.2001.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4 ; do 
    echo $f | sed -E "s/(.*\.[[:digit:]]{4})\..*/\1/"
done
```

produces your desired output.

### explanation

The pattern lets sed look for four digits (`[[:digit:]]{4}`) enclosed in dots (`\.`) and anything (`.*`) in front and behind that pattern. Anything in front including the digits, excluding the dot right behind the four digits is modeled as a group, hence the braces `()`. This group is back-referenced in the substitution with `\1`.